# How to uncheck all Checkboxes inside <tr> by clicking the Checkbox places in last <td> of <tr>

Tags: jquery

Please give the solution for my problem.

I have a table.

If i select the Check box in the last `<td>` tag of `<tr>` then all the check boxes of the same `<tr>` tag should be uncheked.

My code is like this now.

```
var columnText = $('TABLE TBODY TR:first TD:last input:checkbox').change(
   function() {
      alert("Hi");  
      $(this).parents('tr').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Please anyone help me. :-)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that it just doesn't work at all, given that you haven't actually said how this is failing.

Comment: Maybe it might be easier to add a class to the checkbox instead of having such a complicated selector that will only work for the first row and no other row

Comment: I am not sure why the point is to downvote... this person is obviously a new user, please give constructive feedback and help the user get use to the stackoverflow community... :p

Comment: Your script as you posted it works: http://jsfiddle.net/SBjSr/ There must be something wrong, that you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var columnText = $('table tbody tr:first td:last input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  alert("Hi");
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use .closest( selector ) @ http://api.jquery.com/closest/ and the $each iterator

```
$.each($(this).closest('tr').find("td"),function(){
   $(this).attr('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('table tr:first').each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      $el.find('td:last input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if($(this).attr('checked')) {
          $el.find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:last)').attr('checked', false); 
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct, here is a table with some checkboxes in td's

```
<table id="check_test">
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" value=""/><label for="a">a</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" value=""/><label for="b">b</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" id="c" value=""/><label for="c">last</label>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" name="d" id="d" value=""/><label for="d">d</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="e" id="e" value=""/><label for="e">e</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="f" id="f" value=""/><label for="f">last</label>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

to autocheck all checkboxes within a td when the last checkbox is checked :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check_test td").find("input:last").change(function()                    
        $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").attr('checked',true);
    });
});
```